# Where are Laravel Vue env variables?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using **Vue.js 2.0** with **Laravel**. Laravel has a `.env` file that allows you to do:

```
$foo = env('bar', 'somekey');
```

But if I want my variable `bar` in **Vue.js** components, have to do something like this:

*IN BLADE*:

```
var bar = '{{ env('bar') }}';
```

*IN VUE*:

```
data {
    ...
    foo: bar
}
```

This doesn't seem to be the most elegant way of achieving the desired result.

I see that when I run `npm run production` script, there is a part that does:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development ...
```

**So I have 2 questions:**

1. Where is the `env` file that *`development`* is referring to, so I can add my variables to it?
2. How do I access those variables in my Vue components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but here is an article about "Sharing Data in a Laravel/Vue application". https://zaengle.com/blog/layers-of-a-laravel-vue-application

Read the section "Data Transfer Strategies".

```
//Blade Template
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
         'csrf_token => csrf_token(),
         'user'      => $user
    ]); ?>
</script>

<my-custom-vue-component></my-custom-vue-component>


//Vue Component
data(){
    return {
        user: window.Laravel.user
    }
}
```

Comment: The first 2 options do something like what I'm already doing, and the other 2 require me to make an API call for my credentials... It's hard to believe this how the MEAN stack does it.